# Is the feasibility of a system of non-convex quadratic equations and inequations decidable?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, decidability, non-convex-optimization

I would like to know whether the following problem is decidable.

> Given the following system in $x \in [0,1]^n$
>
> $$x^T Q_i x + r_i = 0     \mbox{ for } i = 1, ..., k$$
>
> $$x^T Q_j x + r_j \neq 0  \mbox{ for } j = k+1, ..., t$$
>
> where $r_i, r_j \in [0,1]$ are rational constants and $Q_i, Q_j$ are symmetric indefinite $n \times n$ matrices, decide whether this system is feasible.

According to me (after a series of transformations and added slack variables), the decidability problem above is equivalent to asking whether the global maximum of $q_j^T x$ (a linear term) can be found, subject to non-linear, non-convex quadratic constraints

$$x^T Q_i x + q_i^T x + r_i \leq 0     \mbox{ for } i = 1, ..., u$$

where $x$, $r_i$ and $Q_i$ have the same form as before (but are not identical), $q_i$ is a column vector of length $n$, and $q_i^T$ is the transpose of $q_i$.

The latter formulation of the problem can be viewed as a Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program (QCQP), except that the objective function is linear. And the constraints are, in general, non-linear.
Also note that the latter problem is posed as a decision problem, not purely an optimization problem.

Does either one of these problems have a decidability result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any fixed $n,k,t$, the feasibility question is a first-order formula in the language of real-closed fields; it would have the components of $x$ as existentially quantified variables and the $r$'s and the entries of the $Q$'s as free variables.  Tarski's quantifier elimination theorem for real-closed fields converts this to a propositional combination of equations and inequalities for the free variables.  The quantifier-elimination is algorithmic.  So as long as the components of the $Q$'s are given in such a way that you can algorithmically do arithmetic with them, the feasibility question is decidable.

Comment: My comment/response is too long to fit here, so i posted a new question: Is the first-order theory (with =) of real numbers with addition and multiplication complete and decidable?

Comment: Gavin, yes, it is. That is exactly a consequence of Tarski's theorem.

Comment: Completeness is automatic, since the first-order theory of any single structure is always complete.  Decidability follows from Tarski's theorem.